# SQL sum session durations for users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database table **event_user_login** that is structured as follows:

```
+---------------+-----------------------------+
|  employee_ID  |   date     |session_duration|
+---------------------------------------------+
|   55707       | 2015-04-01 |   20           |
|   55707       | 2015-04-01 |   10           |
|   44251       | 2015-04-01 |   5            |
|   55707       | 2015-04-02 |   10           |
|   44211       | 2015-04-02 |   20           |
+---------------+------------+----------------+
```

*employee_ID column is of type int. date is of type date. session_duration is of type int.*

I wish to run a SQL statement to return to me the DISTINCT employee_ID's, and the sum of the session_durations for that employee.

```
e.g result
+-----------+------------+
|   55707   |    40      |
|   44251   |    5       |
|   44211   |    20      |
+-----------+------------+
```

I am not experienced in using nested SELECT statements, could someone please provide a bit of guidance here?

Comment: select employee_id, sum(session_duration) from event_user_login group by employee_id

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT employee_ID, sum(session_duration)
FROM event_user_login
GROUP BY employee_ID;
```

You don't need a nested select or anything complicated like that. What you're chasing is a very simple aggregation query. The above is essentially saying:

Give me all of the employee_ids, group them so the same ids are together, then add up all of the session_durations for each group of ids, and then return each group, and that sum.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply pala_! How would I modify this to search over multiple tables? My event_user_login table is actually split into monthly tables such as event_user_login_2015_01, event_user_login_2015_02, ... How can I combine this query to look over all tables? Cheers and thanks again

Comment: That would quickly become annoying as you'd have to modify your query every month.